# Query on SQL Server Always On

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, clustering

DC1: (servers are in WSFC): DB_Server1 and DB_Server2

DC2: DB_Server3

DC1 and DC2 servers are located in different geo locations. Is it possible to configure SQL 2017 Always-On/SQL 2017 Distributed Always-On in above environmnet? 
As per my understanding, the servers should be in WSFC, but DC2 DB server is not in cluster, its standalone machine. If it's not possible to configure SQL always-On in above env, please suggest which SQL HA/DR solution i can use...

Comment: Have you looked at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: before posting my question I already cheked MS link. It looks like, It's not possible to configure Distributed Always-On for above setup. Is this my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough information in your question, to definatively say if you can or can not meet your goal with your available resources.

It is possible to [Create a domain-independent availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/domain-independent-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15) that spans physical locations.

Yes it can be done.  How to set up the infrastructure to support it, is going to be out of scope for DBA.se, but you can get help at https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic & https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> DC1: (servers are in WSFC): DB_Server1 and DB_Server2
>
> DC2: DB_Server3
>   Is it possible to configure SQL 2017 Always-On/SQL 2017 Distributed Always-On in above environmnet?

Yes.

The basic, and best solution:

1) Add DB_Server3 to the WSFC and add and add it to the AG, hosting an Async Replica, and optionally with an AG Listener configured to fail over to the second DC.

Or, More complicated:

2) Add DB_Server3 to a *new* WSFC and configure a [Distributed Availability Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15) that spans the two clusters.

Comment: Hi David Browne, The DB_server3 (DC2) is in different domain. I think it is not possible to add DB_server1,DB_server2,DB_server3 in same WSFC. Please correct me If I am wring. Regarding pooint 2 (conigure Distributed AG): in DC2 i have only one server that is DB_Server3, in this case how to create WSFC, need minimum two servers for WSFC. Please correct me If am wrong.

Comment: Is it true that, WSFC is not requirement for SQL 2017? If it's true, can i follow below steps for DAG? Step 1: create the first AG group for dbserver1 and dbserver2, then create another ag group for dbserver3.

Step 2: Then create DAG for two ag groups.